# How to plot points outside certain polygon area in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, polygon

I have been looking around for a method to plot points outside a polygon's area(hexagon in my case). Here's the scenario that I want to achieve, I have a small hexagon located inside a big hexagon. The picture is as follows:

[image: Points outside the small hexagon]

In the picture, I created a small hexagon (whom area indicated in pale red) and generate a random points (three in my case) inside it using `inpolygon`. Problem arise when I want to plot points (red triangles) in big hexagon (indicated in pale purple) **without touching the small hexagon area**. I have look around the net for this simple solutions 3 days to no avail.

**I would really appreciate any helps or guidance I could get**. Thank you so much!

My code is as follows:

```
clear
clc

bighexagon = 20;
smallhexagon = 4;

axis_min = 0;
axis_max = 40; 
axis([axis_min axis_max axis_min axis_max],'square');
hold on

L = linspace(30,390,7); 
bhex_x = bighexagon * (1+cosd(L))'; 
bhex_y = bighexagon*(1+sind(L))';

L2 = linspace(30,390,7); 
shex_x = smallhexagon * (1+cosd(L2))'; 
shex_y = smallhexagon * (1+sind(L2))';

plot(bhex_x,bhex_y,'LineWidth',3);

%---Move small hexagon into big hexagon
shex_vertices_x2(:,1) = shex_x + 16;
shex_vertices_y2(:,1) = shex_y + 16;
plot(shex_vertices_x2(:,1),shex_vertices_y2(:,1),'--k','LineWidth',3);


%---Plot points in small hexagon
no = 3;
point_x2 = (smallhexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no)*2*smallhexagon;
point_y2 = (smallhexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no)*2*smallhexagon;       

inside = inpolygon(point_x2,point_y2,shex_vertices_x2,shex_vertices_y2);

point_x2 = point_x2(inside);
point_y2 = point_y2(inside);

idx2 = randperm(length(point_x2));

point_x2 = point_x2(idx2(1:no));
point_y2 = point_y2(idx2(1:no));

plot(point_x2,point_y2,'ro','MarkerSize',1.5,'LineWidth',1, ...
'MarkerFaceColor','r');

%---Plot points in big hexagon
no2 = 4;
point_x = (bighexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no2)*2*bighexagon;
point_y = (bighexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no2)*2*bighexagon;

inside2 = inpolygon(point_x,point_y,bhex_x,bhex_y);

point_x = point_x(inside2);
point_y = point_y(inside2);

idx = randperm(length(point_x));

point_x = point_x(idx(1:no2));
point_y = point_y(idx(1:no2));

plot(point_x,point_y,'g^','MarkerSize',3,'LineWidth',3, ...
'MarkerFaceColor','g');
```

Comment: if you used `inpolygon` to define point _inside_ the small polygon, you can just use the same method get some point inside the big one but outside the small one. Just define 2 conditions along those lines : `pointvalid = inpolygon(big_polygon) & ~inpolygon(small_polygon)`.

Comment: @Hoki, good point. could have posted it as an answer

Comment: @SanthanSalai, yes I probably would if I had more than 'pseudo-code' to work with, but since the OP didn't post any code, I didn't want to generate a full sample example just to show my point. If the OP shows his code it may be very quick to adjust it to do what it wants, but I won't do it from scratch.

Comment: @Hoki, your point already help me a lot. Thank you so much! I'll include your point and edit the questions so that other users could benefit from this as well.

Comment: @loss. That would be good if you could do that yes (make the question/answer clear for everybody). After all, the whole point of this site is to make others benefit from our learnings.

Comment: @Hoki, I have included the code in the question but I haven't include your points yet since I am still testing it. I will update once it works.

Comment: @Hoki sometimes I only need the name of the function to get me on my way. The OP didn't originally post code but now they have which includes the suggestion we both made, so now I feel it's more confusing for other readers. FWIW I felt that the question was clear enough and, even for a one-liner, an answer was more in keeping with the site guidelines than a comment and more useful for both the OP and future readers (and I wasn't hijacking the answer either - mine predated).

Comment: @xenoclast, just to clear the confusions, my code is not complete yet. If I increase the number of points in big hexagon (e.g. 30), some of the points will be inside the small hexagon (which is not what I want). I am still trying on this part. I would appreciate if you could help me on this.

Comment: @loss I think that with two tests using `inpolygon`, as Hoki suggests, you will be able to solve the problem. My comment was that adding the suggested answers into the text of the question was not necessary, but it was directed at Hoki not you - for your part I thought it was a well posed (and interesting) question. Welcome to the site by the way!

Comment: @xenoclast, thank you! ^_^. I've tried @Hoki suggestion, but it is giving me error at the moment. I'm stuck. It says the `&` is not compatible or something....feel like over the edge at the moment since it suppose to be easy T_T

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Finally! Thank God!.....I feel like jumping!!!! =D. Thank you to you to you both. I'll update with an answer.

Comment: I don't know who told you that, this stuff is hard! Don't worry, it's coming together. Your code at the moment is generating all the points at the same time, randomly, then testing and rejecting them based on the inpolygon test. But this means that you can end up with different numbers of points that pass both tests, so when you try to use the & operator it fails because the vectors are different lengths. I would suggest that you rewrite the 'plot points in...' sections to generate one point and test that against both hexagons. If you need more points you can repeat that operation.

Comment: Glad to hear it. When you update your question to include the answer I would put it in a new section at the end called 'UPDATE', so that people who read the question later aren't confused by the timeline : )

Comment: @xenoclast noted on that! I actually post it on the answer section, which I think will be less confusing for novice user like me =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Thank to `Hoki`'s suggestion, I finally able to work it out.

**Note that I change this part inside the code:**

> `validpoint = inpolygon(point_x,point_y,bhex_x,bhex_y) & ~inpolygon(point_x,point_y,shex_vertices_x2,shex_vertices_y2);`

Hopefully, this clear the confusions and would help other users as well. I would like to thank `Hoki` and `xenoclast` for their help.

The code is as follows:

```
clear
clc

bighexagon = 20;
smallhexagon = 4;

axis_min = 0;
axis_max = 40; 
axis([axis_min axis_max axis_min axis_max],'square');
hold on

L = linspace(30,390,7); 
bhex_x = bighexagon * (1+cosd(L))'; 
bhex_y = bighexagon*(1+sind(L))';

L2 = linspace(30,390,7); 
shex_x = smallhexagon * (1+cosd(L2))'; 
shex_y = smallhexagon * (1+sind(L2))';

plot(bhex_x,bhex_y,'LineWidth',3);

%---Move small hexagon into big hexagon
shex_vertices_x2(:,1) = shex_x + 16;
shex_vertices_y2(:,1) = shex_y + 16;
plot(shex_vertices_x2(:,1),shex_vertices_y2(:,1),'--k','LineWidth',3);


%---Plot points in small hexagon
no = 3;
point_x2 = (smallhexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no)*2*smallhexagon;
point_y2 = (smallhexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no)*2*smallhexagon;       

inside = inpolygon(point_x2,point_y2,shex_vertices_x2,shex_vertices_y2);

point_x2 = point_x2(inside);
point_y2 = point_y2(inside);

idx2 = randperm(length(point_x2));

point_x2 = point_x2(idx2(1:no));
point_y2 = point_y2(idx2(1:no));

plot(point_x2,point_y2,'ro','MarkerSize',1.5,'LineWidth',1, ...
'MarkerFaceColor','r');

%---Plot points in big hexagon
no2 = 30;
point_x = (bighexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no2)*2*bighexagon;
point_y = (bighexagon+20) - rand(1,9*no2)*2*bighexagon;

%---As per Hoki's suggestion, it ensure the points are outside the small hexagon

validpoint = inpolygon(point_x,point_y,bhex_x,bhex_y) & ...
    ~inpolygon(point_x,point_y,shex_vertices_x2,shex_vertices_y2);

point_x = point_x(validpoint);
point_y = point_y(validpoint);

idx = randperm(length(point_x));

point_x = point_x(idx(1:no2));
point_y = point_y(idx(1:no2));

plot(point_x,point_y,'g^','MarkerSize',3,'LineWidth',3, ...
'MarkerFaceColor','g');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your inner hexagon is defined by the vertices then you could use `inpolygon` ([link](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html)) to test whether a given point is inside it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Pls check by adding following two lines after `inside2 = inpolygon(point_x,point_y,bhex_x,bhex_y);`

```
in1 = inpolygon(point_x,point_y,shex_vertices_x2,shex_vertices_y2);
inside2= logical(inside2-in1);
```